# Service Fabric 1.5 deployments failing

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric, appveyor

I am getting the error

```
Unable to Verify connection to Service Fabric cluster
Cluster connection instance is null
```

This only happens on build server. I can publish from visual studio locally with same profile and it works fine, and in the output window the following script is executes, but on build server I get this error with the same script. any ideas?

```
"$buildFolder\APP.Microservices\Scripts\Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1" -ApplicationPackagePath "$buildFolder\APP.Microservices\pkg\Release" -PublishProfileFile "$buildFolder\APP.Microservices\PublishProfiles\cloud-dev-ci.xml" -DeployOnly:$false -ApplicationParameter:@{} -UnregisterUnusedApplicationVersionsAfterUpgrade $false -OverrideUpgradeBehavior 'None' -OverwriteBehavior 'SameAppTypeAndVersion' -SkipPackageValidation:$false -ErrorAction Stop
```

Comment: Do you have a secured cluster? If so, do you have the client certificate installed on the build server?

Comment: No it is unsecured.

Comment: Do you have the clusters' fqdn in the publishprofile? (please use a secured cluster in production)

Comment: fqdn? The connection endpoint is in the publish profile. This was working before updating to 1.5 and also still works from my local machine.

Comment: Is the cluster running in Azure? Which runtime version? 5.6.210?

Comment: Service Fabric version
5.6.210.9494

Comment: Also just noticed something strange in my local publish log

"void](Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -TimeoutSec:10 -WarningAction:'SilentlyContinue' -ConnectionEndpoint:'myendpointxyz123.com'); Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\ServiceFabricSDK.psm1'; Get-ServiceFabricApplicationStatus -ApplicationName 'fabric:/APP.Microservices' -ErrorAction Stop"

Seems to suggest the publish is relying on a service fabric sdk being installed on the machine initiating the publish. I never specifically did this on my builder server.

Comment: If the previous version also relied on the sdk, then appveyor (my builder server provider) must have some version installed by default. Maybe that needs to be updated.

Comment: Maybe not though, looking at past successful build logs it seems that last script only happens from visual studio so probably a product of publishing with vs fabric tools.

Comment: Yes, you need the SDK, as it has the PowerShell modules. And the SDK version should match the cluster version, or be higher

Comment: @LoekD Is the sdk really required just for a deploying an already built service fabric package?

Comment: Yes, it installs the PowerShell commands you use to connect and deploy.

Comment: Okay thanks, now if I can just figure out how to update to a specific version with powershell on appveyor! I appreciate the help!

Comment: @LoekD I have logged into the build server now and updated to latest service fabric sdk and visual studio tools, but I am still getting this error.

Comment: Unable to Verify connection to Service Fabric cluster.
Test-ServiceFabricClusterConnection : Cluster connection instance is null
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service
Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1:143 char:16
+         [void](Test-ServiceFabricClusterConnection)

    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Test-ServiceFabricClusterConnection], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.TestClusterConnection

Comment: @LoekD It is very strange actually I have narrowed it down quite a bit. I can deploy from visual studio only. If I copy the ps script that is used to deploy successfully from the visual studio deploy output and use that in a powershell window I get above error even on my local machine.

Comment: did you call `connect-servicefabriccluster` first? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/test-servicefabricclusterconnection?view=azureservicefabricps